# Sudo not working - "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?"

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, permissions, sudo

I have been trying to allow access to the normal user of an EC2 amazon server ('ec2-user') to a certain library.

I did: "sudo chown -R ec2-user /usr" which I realize now had been a fatal mistake. It worked, but sudo is gone. If I try to use sudo I get: "sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?"

I tried "chmod u+s /usr" like it is suggested in another answer. It does not solve the issue.

I guess that there is something basic I am missing. Forgive my newb ignorance.

Comment: What is your question?  Do you wish to fix the EC2 so it works again?  If so, detatch the EBS volume, attach it to another instance, mount on the instance ie ``mount /dev/xdvf1 /mnt`` then chown sudo back to the correct permissions ``chown 4111 /mnt/usr/bin/sudo`` and then reattach the volume back to the original

Answer (score 0):

The suid bit of the permissions for sudo changes the effective user to the owner of the sudo command file, which you changed to be ec2-user. You need to give ownership of the sudo command back to root.

Comment: Thanks. Can you... tell me how to do that? I am not very fluent with these things.

Comment: While logged in as ec2-user, do "chown root /usr/bin/sudo". This will fix your problem specifically. You probably have problems with other suid programs that also need to be given back to root as well.

Comment: Ok, that resulted with it saying "chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/bin/sudo’: Operation not permitted" . Is it true then that I am not logged in as a root? Or...?

Comment: You need to be logged in as the user that currently owns /usr/bin/sudo.

Comment: If your filesystem has ACLs you may not be able to fix things directly since you currently don't have access to root (as I think that you'll need to be root to change the ACLs for /usr/bin with the setfacl command).

Comment: Ok, I am logged in as ec2-user, which is, as far as I understand... The only user. Is there any other user by default? And if so - how can I log in as this user?

Comment: There are several users by default. You can see them in the /etc/passwd file. "root" is the administrator account and when you use sudo to execute a command, you are running that command with root's admin permissions because root is (or was) the owner of the /usr/bin/sudo command file. When you changed the owner of sudo to be ec2-user, you've basically lost access to the admin account and admin privilege. With most AMIs, you cannot log in as root at all.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to fix that then, without just erasing the whole instance and starting over?

Comment: Since the chown root did not work, I would recommend that you recreate the instance.